# Change the origin of the JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jcomponent

I have a JScrollPanel implemented correctly . I want to be able to draw a graph in the scrolloable area . The JScrollPanel i produced has its origin (x=0,y=0) in the top left corner .

How can i change this so that the origin becomes bottom left corner of the JScrollPane ?In other words the co-ordinate values should increase up and to the right.

I need this because this origin style corresponds to the LANDSCAPE mode in which i want the graph to be visualized . I went through the [JComponent doucmentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html) . I am not sure which API to use .

Comment: probably I'm not alone whos lost in this description, I'm not sure which of (derived) JComponet you want to ... and then to do something wiht

Comment: So, essentially, you want to rotate the view 90 degrees anti-clock wise?

Comment: @mKorbel Apologies if my description is not clear . I am essentially playing around with the co-ordinate system here . The graph i want to plot on the scroll pane has its vertex positions in LANDSCAPE model ( I cannot control the graph ) . Landscape mode means vertex obeys a co -ordinate system where origin is not at the top left corner but at the bottom left ( Essentially what MadProgrammer says . Hence i was thinking if i can get the JscrollPane also to have its origin at bottom left then the direct placing of the graph will not be a problem .

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are correct . I made some more description above .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not able to change to coordinates of where the origin of the JScrollPane is located.  In all of swing the origin is defined as top left.
What you have to do is manually correct the y values.

This is as simple as `int outputY = JScrollPanelObject.getHeight() - inputY;`

This flips the Y values making it appear as if it is increasing up and to the right.

EDIT:
In that case you can grab a `Graphics2D` object just call rotate on it.
in most cases the `Graphics` object handed down from the paint method can be casted to a `Graphics2D`.
I do believe you want to rotate it -90 degrees or -Math.PI/2

Comment: I guess i want to flip my entire co-ordinate system with X increasing upwards and Y increasing right wards.

Comment: yeah, but as he said, it isnt possible. try his suggested method.

Comment: you can pass this rotated graphics object before the children are painted which would then paint the children in this rotated fashion.
But the origin is not changing.  It is just the visual reference that is changing